# Puppeteer - Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

When i set headless: true (without open browser) in Puppeteer i have error Error:

> Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of
>   undefined at **puppeteer_evaluation_script**:3:115

I add that if is headless: false (with open browser) the script works correctly...
From my observations, it appears that the error occurs while performing this function

```
await page.evaluate( () =>
    {
    Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( '.N3ewq' ) ).filter( element => element.textContent == 'Switch' )[0].click();
    });
```

How can I fix it? Thanks for all suggestions

Answer (score 3):

As the other guys said you can use [waitForSelector](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) and [waitForNavigation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) to solve your problem, but you can handle that a little bit better in order to not get errors out of control.

For example, you can do something like that:

```
await page.waitForSelector('.N3ewq',{timeout:3000}).catch(() => console.log('Class N3ewq doesn\'t exist!'));
await page.evaluate(() => {
          if(document.querySelectorAll('#step_next').length > 0){
              Array.from(document.querySelectorAll( '.N3ewq')).filter(element => element.textContent == 'Switch' )[0].click();
          }
      });
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting until the page fully loads before evaluating:

```
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
await page.evaluate( () => {
    Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( '.N3ewq' ) ).filter( element => element.textContent == 'Switch' )[0].click();
});
```

Comment: It's not working :/ now is TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded

Comment: I think it's about that -> The function passed to evaluate is executed in a different context than where you are running your node script. For this reason, you have to explicitly pass variables from your node script to the window script otherwise buttonSelector will be undefined. <- But I'dont know how to solve this problem...

Comment: Wouldn't a page.waitForSelector(selector[, options])  be better?
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options

Answer (score 0):

Try using [wait for selector](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options), So your code will become something like this

```
await page.waitForSelector('.N3ewq');
await page.evaluate(() => {
   Array.from(document.querySelectorAll( '.N3ewq')).filter(element => 
     element.textContent == 'Switch' )[0].click();
});
```